# Python script cannot find the distribution that installed it

Tags: python, easy-install

I am trying to make a script that can be distributed by transferring a .egg file, but after I install the .egg, calling the script from cmd gives an error of this form:

```
C:\Users\286344>testScript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\286344\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6\Scripts\t
estScript.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 444, in _build_master
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 725, in require
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: testScript==0.0
```

I don't think the error is in the script itself, because this same error is apparent in all scripts I try to run this way.

The base script is the simplest possible that I could think of:

```
#!python
print("test")
```

Which easy_install takes and produces in the \Scripts\ directory:

```
#!C:\Users\286344\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6\python.exe
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'testScript==0.0','testScript.py'
__requires__ = 'testScript==0.0'
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.run_script('testScript==0.0', 'testScript.py')
```

And the setup.py is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='testScript',
      version='0.0',
      scripts=['testScript.py'],)
```

the `python setup.py bdist_egg` command completes without error, as well as the `easy_install testScript-0.0-py2.7.egg` command to install. The script does appear in my \Scripts\ directory, which is on the path.

If anyone knows what is going wrong, the help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `#!python` without any path? Didn't think that would work...

Comment: @glglgl It doesn't work to run that script directly, but easy_install changes the shebang to have the appropriate path when you specify that a file is a script in `setup()`.